# Android: Double quotes and "\n" in the SMS body while trying to use default SMS app

Tags: java, android, sms

I am constructing Uri like `Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumbers)` and then using it to create an intent to send SMS like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
```

So, in some SMS apps, a double quotes appears (see screenshot) and the newline symbol is printed as "\n", while in the other apps, everything looks OK. Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

[image]

Comment: I know, it sounds like "something went wrong, please help me", but the client sends me screenshots like this, and I can't reproduce the issue with my phone. Maybe someone have met the same problem.